# LinkedIn REST API authentication suddenly stopped working Android Emulator

Tags: android, rest, linkedin-api

I am using LinkedIn REST API to get user's linkedIn details and it was working until today(For past 1 month).I am getting basic details like name email only.Even it was working till half of today and suddenly it is throwing this error,

```
 Caused by: com.google.code.linkedinapi.client.oauth.LinkedInOAuthServiceException: oauth.signpost.exception.OAuthCommunicationException: Communication with the service provider failed: https://api.linkedin.com/uas/oauth/requestToken
                                                 at com.google.code.linkedinapi.client.oauth.LinkedInOAuthServiceImpl.getOAuthRequestToken(LinkedInOAuthServiceImpl.java:180)
                                                 at in.techchefs.talktemple.login.LinkedInAsyncTask.doInBackground(LinkedInAsyncTask.java:45)
                                                 at in.techchefs.talktemple.login.LinkedInAsyncTask.doInBackground(LinkedInAsyncTask.java:14)
                                                 at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:292)
                                                 at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
                                                 at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231) 
                                                 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112) 
                                                 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587) 
                                                 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818) 
                                              Caused by: oauth.signpost.exception.OAuthCommunicationException: Communication with the service provider failed: https://api.linkedin.com/uas/oauth/requestToken
                                                 at oauth.signpost.AbstractOAuthProvider.retrieveToken(AbstractOAuthProvider.java:214)
                                                 at oauth.signpost.AbstractOAuthProvider.retrieveRequestToken(AbstractOAuthProvider.java:69)
                                                 at com.google.code.linkedinapi.client.oauth.LinkedInOAuthServiceImpl.getOAuthRequestToken(LinkedInOAuthServiceImpl.java:172)
                                                 at in.techchefs.talktemple.login.LinkedInAsyncTask.doInBackground(LinkedInAsyncTask.java:45) 
                                                 at in.techchefs.talktemple.login.LinkedInAsyncTask.doInBackground(LinkedInAsyncTask.java:14) 
                                                 at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:292) 
                                                 at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237) 
                                                 at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231) 
                                                 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112) 
                                                 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587) 
                                                 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818) 
                                              Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: https://api.linkedin.com/uas/oauth/requestToken
```

Here is the code,

```
public class LinkedInAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {
LinkedInActivity mContext;
public static LinkedInApiClientFactory factory;
public static LinkedInOAuthService oAuthService;
public static LinkedInRequestToken liToken;

public static final String LINKEDIN_CONSUMER_KEY = "XXXXXXX";//gave like this for security purpose only.
public static final String LINKEDIN_CONSUMER_SECRET = "XXXXXXX";

public static final String OAUTH_CALLBACK_SCHEME = "x-oauthflow-linkedin";
public static final String OAUTH_CALLBACK_HOST = "callback";
//  public static final String OAUTH_CALLBACK_URL = OAUTH_CALLBACK_SCHEME + "://" + OAUTH_CALLBACK_HOST;
public static String OAUTH_CALLBACK_URL = "x-oauthflow-linkedin://callback";

public LinkedInAsyncTask(LinkedInActivity mContext) {
    this.mContext = mContext;
}


@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    super.onPreExecute();
}


@Override
protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {

    LinkedinDialog.oAuthService = LinkedInOAuthServiceFactory.getInstance().createLinkedInOAuthService(LINKEDIN_CONSUMER_KEY, LINKEDIN_CONSUMER_SECRET);
    LinkedinDialog.factory = LinkedInApiClientFactory.newInstance(LINKEDIN_CONSUMER_KEY, LINKEDIN_CONSUMER_SECRET);

    LinkedinDialog.liToken = LinkedinDialog.oAuthService.getOAuthRequestToken(OAUTH_CALLBACK_URL);

    return null;
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
    super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
   mContext.setWebView();
}
}
```

Please suggest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution!, problem is since I was an running on emulator (which was open for long time) the time data from emulator had a mismatch with linkedIn server which rejects request with even minor time differences.Hence, the only solution is to close and restart the emulator.Hope, this helps someone.